# Is there a possibility in Liquibase to create a changelog between a changelog and a database?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I feel like I´m missing something obvious, but is there a maven goal (or command in normal liquibase) to create a changelog to recreate a database, but as a difference from an existing Changelog. So for example I have a Database with 3 tables and a changelog that creates 2 of these tables, and I want a goal that creates a changelog for the third table.

Using Liquibase version 4.14.0

Answer (score 0):

We have some Liquibase documentation about using Maven available, but as far as I can tell this functionality does not exist yet. You can suggest it on our idea board: https://ideas.liquibase.com

References:

1. https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/home.html
2. https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/home.html
3. https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-update.html

Comment: Correct, support for doing a "diff against a changelog" does not exist. To actually understand all the ins and outs of what exactly gets created in the database would require basically re-implementing the DDL logic of all the different databases.

What you can do instead, though, is apply your existing changelog to an empty database and then diffChangeLog that temporary database with your "complete" database